# イーサリアムで送金エラー `Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value`

Tags: javascript, ethereum

テストネットワークでGethを起動し、送金しようとすると、、`Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value` というエラーが発生し送金に失敗してしまいます。

> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]) - 20000 * eth.gasPrice

を見ればわかるように資金が足りていないということは無さそうなのですが、なぜでしょう。どなたかお教えいただけると嬉しいです。

```
    $ geth --networkid 11 --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 --datadir ~/data_testnet console 2>> ~/data_testnet/geth.log

    Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

    instance: Geth/v1.8.0-unstable-722bac84/darwin-amd64/go1.9.3
    coinbase: 0x3aabdf52f4b29276847f0a767410cf3cad3d228e
    at block: 593 (Sun, 28 Jan 2018 21:08:20 JST)
    datadir: /Users/suzukikeita/data_testnet
     modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

    > eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])
    2.965e+21
    > eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1])
    0
    > eth.gasPrice
    18000000000
    > personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])
    > eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei("1", "ether")})
    Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
        at web3.js:3143:20
        at web3.js:6347:15
        at web3.js:5081:36
        at <anonymous>:1:1
    > eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei("1", "ether"), gas:20000})
    Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
        at web3.js:3143:20
        at web3.js:6347:15
        at web3.js:5081:36
        at <anonymous>:1:1
    > eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]) - 20000 * eth.gasPrice
    2.9649996399999996e+21
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/110971

Answer (score 0, accepted):

genesis.jsonのchainIdと--networkidの値を合わせる必要がある。
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15983